# getElementsByTagName always return the same NodeValue

Tags: php, getelementsbytagname

I can see the name of the node changes as I change the name of the element that I am searching for. But I keep seeing the node value as  "Silverbacks Golden eyes" even if I enter "root" as the element that I am searching for. Why is that?

```
<?php 

$xmlString = <<<XML
<root>
<teams>
<team>Silverbacks</team>
<team foo="winner">Golden eyes </team>
</teams>
</root>
XML;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($xmlString);
$teams = $dom->getElementsByTagName("root"); 
foreach($teams as $team){
  echo $team->nodeName . " and the value of the node is " .$team->nodeValue . "\n"; //always return Silverbacks Golden eyes

}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you Syscal for answering my question. I would expect it to be Null or nothing as the root does not have any text or NodeValue. If you say that according to the specification, then it should display text from its descendants, then may be you are right..

Comment: Sorry, I've not see your comment because it wasn't under my answer. Yes, I said that's how `nodeValue` works DOM in PHP according to the documentation. I didn't know you wanted more because your question was _"Why is that?"_.

Answer (score 0):

Because `nodeValue` contains the text content of this node and its descendants.

According to the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.nodevalue),

> nodeValue
>
> The value of this node, depending on its type. Contrary to the W3C specification, the node value of DOMElement nodes is equal to **DOMNode::textContent** instead of NULL.

So, the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.textcontent) of `textContent`:

> textContent
>
> The text content of this node **and its descendants**.